# How do I search for services that have a space in there name in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, regex

I am trying to get a list of services whose name contains a space, for example SQL Server services. To my surprise, the following statement does not return a single record. It seems that the space has a special meaning and is not parsed literally as I have expected.

```
get-service | where-object name -match 'sql server'
```

What is PowerShell's canonical way to match a string that contains a space?

Comment: Curiously, `get-service | where-object name -match ' '` returns me 9 services with a space in the name. I assume you get 0?

Comment: Maybe consider `name` and `displayname`.  Which one do you need to consider?

Comment: @HelpingHand you're of course right. I *assumed* without verification that `name` is what is actually the `displayname`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Service Control Manager (SCM) is responsible for managing the database of services.  When you create a new service, using the command line tool `sc.exe` or directly using the SCM Windows API calls, e.g. ([CreateServiceA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-createservicea)) you can specify a `ServiceName` and `DisplayName`.

> lpServiceNameD
>
> The name of the service to install. The maximum string length is 256
>   characters. The service control manager database preserves the case of
>   the characters, but service name comparisons are always case
>   insensitive. Forward-slash (/) and backslash () are not valid service
>   name characters.
>
> lpDisplayName
>
> The display name to be used by user interface programs to identify the
>   service. This string has a maximum length of 256 characters. The name
>   is case-preserved in the service control manager. Display name
>   comparisons are always case-insensitive.

If you look in the registry at the list of services which is maintained by the SCM you will see the `ServiceName` value under the following key as the unique value:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\[ServiceName]

When you use tools such as SC.exe or scripting languages such as VBScript, PowerShell to interact with the SCM you typically (but not always) have to use the `ServiceName` value rather than the `DisplayName` to query/stop/start, etc...

When you view the MMC Services snap-in (services.msc), the `Name` column is actually the `DisplayName` of the service rather than the `ServiceName` value.

The `Services` tab in Task Manager does display both however it is still confusing as the `Description` column isn't the description of the service (services can also have descriptions) but the `ServiceName`.  Understandable that they get mixed up.